# How to run SVN import without any dialogues

Tags: perl, shell, svn, import, command

Will the parameter `--non-interactive` work for import? Example:

```
svn import -m "SVN Project created" --username $NAME --password $PASS "$tempProjectPath" "$SVN"
```

Result line:

```
svn import -m "SVN Project created" --username $NAME --password $PASS --non-interactive "$tempProjectPath" "$SVN"
```

I use this line in a Perl script to automatically import a folder into a repository. That's why the comment and password dialogs are inappropriate for me.
I use FreeBSD OS.

I tried to check it manually by importing an empty dir to repository. Example:

```
svn import -m "Manual import Test 1" --username Maxus --password 1111 --non-interactive "/tmp/reti" "svn://192.168.0.57"
```

But nothing happened.

Maybe, you have another idea - how to execute shell command `svn import` in Perl without dialogs for commit comments or passwords? Or how I can ignore/complete those dialogs from a shell command?

Comment: It's not clear to me if you tried running this on the command line...did you? Also, the SVN::Client docs for `import` say `Import file or directory $path into repository directory $url at head.` Are you sure you don't need to append a directory name to your URL?

Comment: This command will be run in command line by Perl script. $url is used without directory name for import $path into repository root. I could be wrong. I will try you suggestion.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to run it in Perl. But if you try it on the command line and it fails, you know Perl is not the issue. Please run your raw command (`svn import -m "Manual import Test 1" --username Maxus --password 1111 --non-interactive "/tmp/reti" "svn://192.168.0.57"`) in a shell (e.g. `bash`) and update your question with the results. This will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Can you `svn ls -v svn://192.168.0.57`? I suppose - no, because svn://-served repos **always** have some trailing path in URL even for repo-root

Comment: @LazyBadger, I run your command and it is works.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I run my command in shell and result was nothing: `[root@svn /home/user]# svn import -m "Manual import Test 1" --username Maxus --password 1111 --non-interactive "/tmp/reti" "svn://192.168.0.57"`

`[root@svn /home/user]# _`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, but when I run command with `... "svn://192.168.0.57/reti"` its works fine (result is `Committed revision 310.`). I cannot understand why error does not appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL for a repo served with `svnserve` has three parts:

```
svn://
server/
path/to/repo
```

As Lazy Badger pointed out in the comments (and as you yourself discovered by running on the command line), you are missing the `path/to/repo` part. `svnserve` will not know which repo you are trying to access unless you give it a path.

If you used the `--root=dir` option when you started `svnserve`, the path you give in the URL will be interpreted relative to `dir`.

Now, based on your last comment, you already know that the command works on the command line when you put a path in the URL. Use that URL in your Perl command and it should work.

Comment: So, as result with your answer, the parameter `--non-interactive` is sufficient for execute shell command `svn import` without dialogs for commit comments or passwords?

Comment: @BohdanKuts I don't understand your comment. You yourself said in a comment that running `svn import` in the shell with `--non-interactive` and a directory in your URL works. What more do you need to know?

Comment: I just wanted to clarify whether it is correct and sufficient, because the question was raised that way.
Excuse me for my bad language.

Comment: @BohdanKuts Yes, `--non-interactive` should be sufficient to prevent you from being prompted. Your language is fine, I just didn't understand if you needed more information.